# Automação selenium Webdriver com python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando o selenium WebDriver com python para logar em um site para fazer algumas tarefas, estou conseguindo clicar em login, más ele não pega o input que peço para digitar.

Este é o código selenium:

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')

url = "https://gool.cittati.com.br/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='listaIcones']//ul//li//input[@id='ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano']")
login.click()

usarname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_divCampos']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_pnlLogin']//div[@class='user']//input[@id='ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin']").send_keys("username")
#password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_divCampos']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_pnlSenha']").send_keys("password")

driver.quit()
```

E este o código html que estou tentando acessar:

```
 <div class="form">
<div id="ucLogarUsuario_divCampos" class="campos" onkeydown="return logar(event);">
        <div id="ucLogarUsuario_pnlLogin">
                
            <label>
                Login</label>
            <div class="user">
                <input name="ucLogarUsuario$txtLogin" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin" tabindex="1" />
            </div>
        
            </div>
        <div id="ucLogarUsuario_pnlSenha">
                
            <label>
                Senha</label>
            <div class="user">
                <input name="ucLogarUsuario$txtSenha" type="password" maxlength="15" id="ucLogarUsuario_txtSenha" tabindex="2" class="userFocus" value="" />
            </div>
        
            </div>
```

Quando executo o código selenium mostra a seguinte mensagem:
**selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable**

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo ?

Comment: pode ser que o elemento ainda não esteja disponível, tente aidcionar um *wait* para alguardar alguns segundos

Comment: Você notou se ao tentar preencher esses campos, eles estão visíveis na tela de modo que você mesmo sem automação conseguiria digitar neles, ou se estavam por trás de uma div ou algo semelhante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O elemento ainda não está disponível para interação, para resolver isso vc pode usar uma técnica de espera explícita como abaixo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver.get("https://gool.cittati.com.br/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f")
driver.find_element_by_id('ucTrocarModulo_btnIconeUrbano').click()

txt_username_locator = (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_divCampos']//div[@id='ucLogarUsuario_pnlLogin']//div[@class='user']//input[@id='ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin']")
# Recomendo mudar o locator acima para (By.ID, "ucLogarUsuario_txtLogin"), fica mais legível e preciso
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(txt_username_locator))
element.send_keys("username")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!